# How to export Octave plot with latex to PDF file

Tags: pdf, plot, octave

I often use latex in my octave plot titles or labes for example `title('Angle \theta in deg');`. The latex renders fine in the default plot viewer in octave, but it does not when I save it as an pdf:

This is what I see in the plot window (screenshot):
[image: This is what I see in the plot window (screenshot)]

This is what happens when I print it with

`print('bessel.png', 'png');
print('bessel.eps', 'eps', '-mono');`:[image]

And this is what happens when I export it to a .pdf from the plot viewers context menu:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/lrjlmbhlaar20d1/untitled.pdf?dl=0

My question is how I can export it to a .pdf File with the latex formatting, because screenshots are pretty low quality?

EDIT: The requested informations from the comments:

- I am on windows 7 64-bit
- Octave Version: 4.0.0
- Latex is installed
- I simply used the plot example code from the octave website and added plot annotations with latex, with the provided code
- I use gnuplot

Comment: I can't play around with your code and see for myself because you didn't provide any, but latex symbols seem to work on my linux setup in general. So just general advice. What OS are you. Is latex installed? Try changing the 'renderer' in the figure properties, that may have something to do with it. Also, you can totally go with the screenshot method if you increase your desktop size (on linux you can just increase the panning with `xrandr`).

Comment: Printing latex symbols with the OpenGL renderer was implemented in 2015: http://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?42320 Your question lacks your uses Octave version and if you're using gnuplot or an OpenGL based toolkit. Also see http://wiki.octave.org/Printing_with_FLTK HowTo use full LaTex support

Comment: Since you are using 4.0 -> update to GNU Octave 4.2

Comment: Thanks, updating to the latest octave version fixed my problem.